# Ansible - malformed block was encountered while loading a block

Tags: ansible

trying to run a playbook:

```
---
- name: azure authorization
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: true
  tasks: 
    - azure_authorization_configuration
```

where task look like:

```
---
- name:
  stat: >
    path="{{ azure_subscription_authorization_configuration_file_dir }}"
  register: stat_dir_result
  tags:
    - azure
```

and defaults main file look like:

```
---
azure_subscription_authorization_configuration_file_dir: '~/.azure/'
```

Directories tree look like:

```
├── hosts
├── playbooks
│   └── azure_authorization_playbook.yml
├── roles
│   ├── az_auth
│   │   ├── defaults
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
```

Ansible version: 2.9.1
Ansible playbook command line snippet:

```
/> ansible-playbook "/Users/user/Dev/Ansible/playbooks/azure_authorization_playbook.yml"
```

Output:

```
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

ERROR! A malformed block was encountered while loading a block
```

Don't have any idea which block was encountered while loading a which block, can anyone tell me where is the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I know how my playbook should look like, it was:

```yaml
---
- name: azure authorization
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: true
  tasks: 
    - azure_authorization_configuration
```

Should be:

```yaml
---
- name: azure authorization
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: true
  roles: 
    - azure_authorization_configuration
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is clearly coming from your playbook, because it doesn't call any roles or load any other playbooks. That is, if I put this in a file:

```
---
- name: azure authorization
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: true
  tasks: 
    - azure_authorization_configuration
```

And try to run it, I get the same error.  The issue is the entry in your `tasks` block. A task should be a dictionary, but you've provided only a string:

```
  tasks: 
    - azure_authorization_configuration
```

You include an example of a correctly written task in your question. If we put that into your playbook, it would look like:

```
- name: azure authorization
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: true
  tasks: 
    - name:
      stat: >
        path="{{ azure_subscription_authorization_configuration_file_dir }}"
      register: stat_dir_result
      tags:
        - azure
```

Comment: Allright, now i managed to run this as I intent to. Swiching tasks with roles in my playbook. :)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because i had a syntax error in my playbook. Note the use of colons(':') in your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was the error in the role. i missed ":"

the wrong code

```
$ cat main.yml
---
# tasks file for db.local

- include pre_install.yml
- include my_sql.yml
```

the good code:

```
$ cat main.yml
---
# tasks file for db.local

- include: pre_install.yml
- include: my_sql.yml
```